# disallow window open in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.open

How can I disable `window.open()` using html, javascript, jQuery...?
I mean block any window open attempt, making "not-working" all existing window.open() functions.
 Which are the best ways to do it? (working also in case of iframes)

Comment: Not sure if it's possible. Can't just disable JS altogether?

Comment: websites that disable browser features are a blight.  if you were hosting my website in an iframe on your website and disabled `window.open` from working in my code, we wouldn't be working together long....

Answer (score 9):

```
//for iframes:
$.each($('iframe'), function() {
    this.contentWindow.open = function (url, windowName, windowFeatures) {
        //iframe window.open caught!
    };
});

//for window:
window.open = function (url, windowName, windowFeatures) {
    //window.open caught!
};
```

Comment: You could always create a new iframe at the time you want to use an open function, ond use the `open` function of that newly created iframe. So this is not a real protection.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be polluting the global namespace, but you could simply override the `window.open` method...

```
window.open = function (url, windowName, windowFeatures) {
    console.log('not opening a window');
}
```

Comment: um..are you saying that your code is isolated in an iframe?

Comment: I need to prevent window.open() also in the case of iframes

Comment: Then override `window.open` inside iframes as well.